# How to find public variables from the inspector?

Tags: unity-game-engine

If I have a code with a huge amount of variables, is there a quick way to find the variables which I can see in the inspector tab?

I tried searching by name, but I don't see corresponding public variables so far.

Answer (score 1):

The ones you can see in the inspector are those that are both:

- `public` or marked `[SerializeField]`
- Not marked `[HideInInspector]`

You may want to consider reorganizing your class so that all the public properties are arranged together and all the protected together and all the private together, etc.

Comment: Thank you very much! What do you mean by reorganizing the class? Is it possible to display a list of all public/private/protected variables, using some sorting features of MonoDeevelop or VisualStudio or another code editor? Or You mean rewriting the code (which is not an option in my case, since I'm trying to understand the code, initially created not by me).

Comment: No, I mean *edit the class* so that the different visibilities are all grouped together. Rather than having properties stuck wherever it seemed like a good place at the time, organize them. Sort them. Move them around. Don't worry, nothing will break.

Comment: Private variables with [SerializeField] are also displayed in the inspector.

Comment: @ElDuderino Good point. I wasn't sure and couldn't quickly check. Edited that in.